# Can preferences be accessed in an XML layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working to implement some simple preferences to an app I have and I am trying to figure out how to use a preference to manipulate a view defined in an XML file. I have a List with the following LinearLayout (player_row.xml) being used for each row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/player_icon"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/player_name"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:textColor="#F0F0F0"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/player_score"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:textColor="#F0F0F0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Right now I am specifying the textSize attribute manually. I'd like to create a preference menu that lets the user select from several options, say "Small", "Medium", and "Large". I figure I should be able to set up the arrays for the entry and font sizes and then reference that in player_row.xml, but I don't seem to be able to.

preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:key="preference_main">
   <ListPreference
      android:key="fontSizePreference"
      android:title="Font size"
      android:entries="@array/fontSizeList"
      android:entryValues="@array/fontSizeList_Values"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="fontSizeList">
    <item>Small</item>
    <item>Medium</item>
    <item>Large</item>
  </string-array>
  <string-array name="fontSizeList_Values">
    <item>22sp</item>
    <item>26sp</item>
    <item>30sp</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

If this can't be done, what is the appropriate way to configure a layout using preferences? My searching has led me to find multiple resources on accessing the preferences programmatically but none of that seems to be the appropriate way to configure a layout defined in an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the procedure you are looking for is:

1. Create settings screen & activity
2. Once the user saves settings, let your backing PreferenceActivity save the settings into a file (using `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREF_FONT_SIZE, yourSetting).commit()`
3. In your main activity#onCreate, load the layout using setContentView
4. Load your preferences there as well
5. Get the views via `findViewById` and set the font size as it's loaded from the preferences

Comment: That's what I was thinking I would need to do. I was kind of hoping there would be a way to do it all via the layout file.

Comment: How could that work? You would need another XML mapping file, or at least a reference from the layout.xml file to the setting.. not to speak of default values, invalid types etc.. I think good like it is now. ;-)

Comment: Well you specify a key, I wasn't sure if perhaps it would automatically generate a resource, for example @pref/font_size or something along those lines. It's not a huge deal either way I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something fundamental.

Comment: Technically that could work. But as said it would introduce more work, as u then MUST have unique key names along all your preference pages (imagine font sizes for different parts of your activity). I would like a syntax like `android:textSizePrefOverlayout="@pref/font_size_list"` then, please. :-}

Comment: That or it seems it could be implemented with a state type item similar to how drawables and colors can work. I'm not sure how your example of creating a secondary mapping file would work though. That would require the ability to populate resources at run time, which I did not think you could do. It seems the necessary complexity makes it obvious that this is not the right choice. Thanks!